# if parent and child processes append to same file, do lseek() and write() need to be atomic?

Tags: unix, fork, atomic, lseek

**Problem Statement**

One process opens a file for appending (assume there is no O_APPEND, appending here means first `lseek()` to the file end then `write()`), and then forks a child. The two dependent processes append to the file simultaneously. Assume that `lseek()` and `write()` are both atomic. Give an example to discuss the necessity of having `lseek()` and `write()` be an atomic operation in this scenario.

**My Thoughts**

1. The current file offset is stored in the entry in open file table, and that entry is shared by the 2 dependent processes.
2. `write()` updates the offset to the end of the data just written.

These 2 points guarantee that even in the following scenario, the data written by `P2` won't be overwritten by `P1`.

```
P1 lseek()
P2 lseek()
P2 write()  // after this operation, the offset still points to the file end
P1 write()
```

**My Problem**

So, do `lseek()` and `write()` still need to be one atomic operation in this specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it's the wording making me question myself.

The answer is that they don't have to be an atomic operation in this specific case.